# SQL Server 2016 Enterprise silent install

Tags: installation, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2016 Enterprise unattended and I can not do.

I have the original ".iso" image (SHA-1: 4B782D6B2512ED1844EF2B2549DB2C586D6BE88E)

```
;SQL Server 2016 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

; Especifica un flujo de trabajo de instalación, como INSTALL, UNINSTALL o UPGRADE. Es un parámetro necesario. 

ACTION="Install"

; Especifica que el programa de instalación de SQL Server no debe mostrar la declaración de privacidad cuando se ejecute desde la línea de comandos. 

SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False"

; Con la especificación de este parámetro y la aceptación de los términos de Microsoft R Open y Microsoft R Server, reconoce que ha leído y comprendido los términos de uso. 

IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="True"

; Use el parámetro /ENU para instalar la versión en inglés de SQL Server en el sistema operativo Windows traducido. 

ENU="False"

; La instalación no mostrará ninguna interfaz de usuario. 

QUIET="False"

; El programa de configuración solo mostrará el progreso, sin la interacción del usuario. 

QUIETSIMPLE="True"

; Parámetro que controla el comportamiento de la interfaz de usuario. Los valores válidos son Normal para la interfaz de usuario completa, AutoAdvance para una interfaz de usuario simplificada y 
; EnableUIOnServerCore para omitir la parte gráfica de la instalación de Server Core. 

; UIMODE="Normal"

; Especifique si el programa de configuración de SQL Server debe detectar e incluir actualizaciones del producto. Los valores válidos son True y False o 1 y 0. De forma predeterminada, 
; el programa de configuración de SQL Server incluirá las actualizaciones que encuentre. 

UpdateEnabled="True"

; Si se proporciona este parámetro, el equipo usará Microsoft Update para comprobar las actualizaciones. 

USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="True"

; Especifica las características que se van a instalar, desinstalar o actualizar. La lista de las características de nivel superior incluye SQL, AS, RS, IS, MDS y Herramientas. 
; La característica SQL instalará el motor de base de datos, la replicación, el texto completo y el servidor de Data Quality Services (DQS). La característica Herramientas instalará los componentes compartidos. 

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,ADVANCEDANALYTICS,FULLTEXT,POLYBASE,AS,RS,SQL_SHARED_MR,RS_SHP,RS_SHPWFE,CONN,IS,BC,SDK,BOL,DREPLAY_CTLR,DREPLAY_CLT,SNAC_SDK,MDS
; FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,ADVANCEDANALYTICS,FULLTEXT,DQ,POLYBASE,AS,RS,SQL_SHARED_MR,RS_SHP,RS_SHPWFE,DQC,CONN,IS,BC,SDK,BOL,DREPLAY_CTLR,DREPLAY_CLT,SNAC_SDK,MDS

; Especifique la ubicación en la que el programa de configuración de SQL Server obtendrá actualizaciones del producto. Los valores válidos son "MU" para buscar en Microsoft Update, una ruta de acceso de carpeta válida, una ruta de acceso relativa, como .\MisActualizaciones, o un recurso compartido UNC. De forma predeterminada, el programa de configuración de SQL Server buscará en Microsoft Update o en el servicio Windows Update mediante Windows Server Update Services. 

UpdateSource="MU"

; Muestra el uso de los parámetros de la línea de comandos 

HELP="False"

; Especifica que el registro de instalación detallado debe redireccionarse a la consola. 

INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Especifica que el programa de configuración debe realizar la instalación en WOW64. Este argumento de la línea de comandos no se admite en sistemas IA64 ni de 32 bits. 

X86="False"

; Especifique una instancia predeterminada o con nombre. MSSQLSERVER y SQLExpress son las instancias predeterminadas de las ediciones que no son Express y de las Express, respectivamente. Se requiere este parámetro al instalar el motor de base de datos de SQL Server (SQL), Analysis Services (AS) o Reporting Services (RS). 

INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER2016"

; Especifique el directorio de instalación raíz de los componentes compartidos. Este directorio no cambia después de instalar los componentes compartidos. 

INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Especifique el directorio de instalación raíz de los componentes compartidos WOW64. Este directorio no cambia después de instalar los componentes compartidos WOW64. 

INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Especifique el identificador de instancia de las características de SQL Server que ha indicado. Las estructuras de directorios y del Registro, así como los nombres de los servicios SQL Server incorporarán el identificador de instancia de SQL Server. 

INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER2016"

; The account used by the Distributed Replay Client service. 

CLTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client"

; The result directory for the Distributed Replay Client service. 

CLTRESULTDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\DReplayClient\ResultDir"

; The startup type for the Distributed Replay Client service. 

CLTSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; The working directory for the Distributed Replay Client service. 

CLTWORKINGDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\DReplayClient\WorkingDir"

; The account used by the Distributed Replay Controller service. 

CTLRSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Controller"

; The startup type for the Distributed Replay Controller service. 

CTLRSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; The Windows account(s) used to grant permission to the Distributed Replay Controller service. 

CTLRUSERS="ESCRITORIO\MyUser"

; Especifica en que modo se instala el servidor de informes. 
; Valor predeterminado: “FilesOnly”  

RSINSTALLMODE="DefaultNativeMode"

; Especifica en qué modo se instala el servidor de informes.  
; Valor predeterminado: “SharePointFilesOnlyMode”  

RSSHPINSTALLMODE="SharePointFilesOnlyMode"

; PolybasePdwUserNameConfigDescription 

PBENGSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red"

; PolybasePdwStartupConfigDescription 

PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; PolybaseDmsUserNameConfigDescription 

PBDMSSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red"

; PolybaseDmsStartupConfigDescription 

PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; PolybaseScaleOutDescription 

PBSCALEOUT="False"

; PolybasePortRangeDescription 

PBPORTRANGE="16450-16460"

; TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription 

SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; TelemetryStartupConfigDescription 

SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; ASTelemetryStartupConfigDescription 

ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; ASTelemetryUserNameConfigDescription 

ASTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SSASTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; TelemetryStartupConfigDescription 

ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription 

ISTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SSISTELEMETRY130"

; Especifique el directorio de instalación. 

INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Nombre de cuenta del Agente 

AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; Iniciar servicio automáticamente después de la instalación.  

AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Tipo de inicio para Integration Services. 

ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Cuenta para Integration Services: Dominio\usuario o cuenta del sistema. 

ISSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MsDtsServer130"

; El nombre de la cuenta con que se ejecuta el servicio de Analysis Services. 

ASSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSOLAP$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; Controla la configuración de tipo de inicio del servicio después de haberse creado. 

ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Intercalación que debe usar Analysis Services. 

ASCOLLATION="Modern_Spanish_CI_AS"

; La ubicación de los archivos de datos de Analysis Services. 

ASDATADIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER2016\OLAP\Data"

; La ubicación de los archivos de registro de Analysis Services. 

ASLOGDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER2016\OLAP\Log"

; La ubicación de los archivos de copia de seguridad de Analysis Services. 

ASBACKUPDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER2016\OLAP\Backup"

; La ubicación de los archivos temporales de Analysis Services. 

ASTEMPDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER2016\OLAP\Temp"

; La ubicación de los archivos de configuración de Analysis Services. 

ASCONFIGDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER2016\OLAP\Config"

; Especifica si el proveedor MSOLAP puede ejecutarse en proceso. 

ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1"

; Especifica la lista de cuentas de administrador que se deben aprovisionar. 

ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="ESCRITORIO\MyUser"

; Especifica el modo de servidor de la instancia de Analysis Services. Los valores válidos son MULTIDIMENSIONAL y TABULAR. El valor predeterminado es MULTIDIMENSIONAL. 

ASSERVERMODE="MULTIDIMENSIONAL"

; Puerto de comunicación TCP del brick de CM 

COMMFABRICPORT="0"

; Cómo usará la matriz las redes privadas 

COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"

; Cómo se protegerá la comunicación entre bricks 

COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"

; Puerto TCP usado por el brick de CM 

MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"

; Tipo de inicio para el servicio SQL Server. 

SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Nivel para habilitar la característica FILESTREAM en (0, 1, 2 o 3). 

FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

; Establézcalo en "1" para habilitar RANU para SQL Server Express. 

ENABLERANU="False"

; Especifica una intercalación de Windows o SQL que se va a utilizar para el motor de base de datos. 

SQLCOLLATION="Modern_Spanish_CI_AS"

; Cuenta para el servicio de SQL Server: Dominio\Usuario o cuenta de sistema. 

SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; Establezca el valor como "True" para habilitar la inicialización de archivo instantánea para el servicio SQL Server. Si se habilita, la Configuración concederá el privilegio de realización de tareas de mantenimiento de volumen al SID del servicio de motor de la base de datos. Esto puede dar lugar a la divulgación de información, ya que se podría permitir a una entidad de seguridad no autorizada el acceso a contenido eliminado. 

SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="False"

; Cuentas de Windows que se suministran como administradores del sistema de SQL Server. 

SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="ESCRITORIO\MyUser"

; El número de archivos de TempDB del motor de base de datos. 

SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="4"

; Especifica el tamaño inicial en MB del archivo de datos de TempDB de un motor de base de datos. 

SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8"

; Especifica el incremento en MB del crecimiento automático de cada archivo de datos de TempDB en cada motor de base de datos. 

SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64"

; Especifica el tamaño inicial en MB del archivo de registro de TempDB del motor de base de datos. 

SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8"

; Especifica el incremento en MB del crecimiento automático del archivo de registro de TempDB del motor de base de datos. 

SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64"

; Aprovisione el usuario actual como administrador del sistema del motor de base de datos para %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Express. 

ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False"

; Especifique 0 para deshabilitar el protocolo TCP/IP, o 1 para habilitarlo. 

TCPENABLED="1"

; Especifique 0 para deshabilitar el protocolo Named Pipes, o 1 para habilitarlo. 

NPENABLED="0"

; Tipo de inicio para el servicio SQL Server Browser. 

BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Especifica la cuenta bajo la que debe ejecutarse el servicio NT del servidor de informes. Cuando se omite o si el valor es una cadena vacía, la cuenta integrada predeterminada para el sistema operativo actual.
; La parte del nombre de usuario RSSVCACCOUNT tienen una longitud máxima de 20 caracteres y
; La parte del dominio de RSSVCACCOUNT tiene una longitud máxima de 254 caracteres. 

RSSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; Indica el modo de instalación del servicio NT del servidor de informes. Cuando aparece 
; Manual - La instalación del servicio se realiza en modo manual (predeterminada).
; Automatic - La instalación del servicio se realiza en modo automático.
; Disabled - El servicio está deshabilitado 

RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Add description of input argument EXTSVCACCOUNT 

EXTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad$MSSQLSERVER2016"

; Add description of input argument FTSVCACCOUNT 

FTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$MSSQLSERVER2016"
```

**DOS command**

```
Setup.exe /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /CONFIGURATIONFILE="SilentInstall.ini"
```

**Error**

[image: Error]

I followed the advice in this post, but it does not work.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd47d052-66a7-4cdb-82c0-68f867ecda0d/error-during-unattended-install-of-sql-2012-setting-cltresultdir-does-not-exist?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Any idea? Thx!

Comment: Are you running that command "As administrator"?   Exactly which "advice" from that link did you follow?

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Yes, i running that command "As administrator". I followed the advice of response they chose as correct.

Comment: -2068578304 = 0x84B40000; exit facility code 1204. Unfortunately, this is a bit of a catch-all error code for installation failures and I could not find any information on precisely *what* triggers this, though it might be an issue with the SQL Server service account or its credentials.